# Aspect J implementing in Titanium Android Module

Tags: android, aspectj, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

I have tried to include Aspect J runtime library in to by creating titanium android module project in Titanium Studio & it was successful. Is there any luck to use aspect j pointcuts inside of a .aj files by adding those in module project, for Titanium mobile project (android)? Since as far as I can see aspect j (run time aspect not compile time) is not working in this scenario. Is there any answer for this? 
-- Thanks

Comment: is it working on native android?

Comment: yes, however for me seems to be it's not working for titanium mobile (android) via titanium module. my question is, is this possible and anyone tried this one? or why is this not working in titanium as i described ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime aspectj wont work for a number of reasons - not the least of which being that Android uses a completely different virtual machine than the JVM to run on - and it uses a completely different bytecode format.

The reason compile-time-weaving can work for AspectJ is because the way android has a build step where it can convert java bytecode into dex bytecode.